# how to hide #error in textbox in access form

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-office

i have a form in access 2010 with an calculated age textbox, the box show #ERROR until date is entered!

=DLookUp("Age","Project Count & Age", "National_ID = "&[Forms]![Promoters Form]![National_ID])

Thank you in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the age textbox and National_ID both on [Promoters Form]? Try:
`=DLookUp("Age", "Project Count & Age", "National_ID = " & Nz([National_ID], 0))`

Otherwise, don't use DLookup(). Domain aggregates can perform slowly in forms and report and should be a last resort. Usually, better options:

1. Combobox for selecting National_ID with multiple columns of fields from [Project Count & Age] and then a textbox with expression that references the Age column of combobox
2. Include lookup table in the form RecordSource, join type "Include all records from [primary table] and only those from [lookup table] that match". Bind textbox to field from lookup table, set Locked Yes and TabStop No. However, if [Project Count & Age] is an aggregate query, this approach will not work.

Advise no spaces or special characters/punctuation (underscore is only exception) in naming convention.